# AWS: Can I connect two DBs to Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

Natively Beanstalk brings one Database with it.

I am having an application were we store Data encrypted in one DB and corresponding keys in a second DB. The app itself is a node/React app.

Can I connect two databases to Beanstalk?

I imagine like having the app in Beanstalk and in the same VPC but different subnets (private) the two databases. They which are connected to the app and are protected by SGs and NACLs.

[image]

Am I'm plainly wrong or perhaps on track concerning my idea?

Could you maybe provide a concept like a small drawing how you would approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from doing this. You would obviously need to configure the VPC subnets and DB security groups correctly to allow the Beanstalk application to access the databases. Then you would simply configure the DB connection settings as custom Elastic Beanstalk environment variables and configure your application to use those variables to establish connections to the databases.